# Joint pdf of discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Consider two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, where $X$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed on the set $\{0,1\}$. Thus, the cdfs are given by 
$F_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & x <0\\
x & 0 \leq x <1\\
1 &  else
\end{cases}$

and

$F_Y(y) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & y <0\\
1/2 & 0 \leq y <1\\
1 &  else.
\end{cases}$

Consider the random variable $Z = (X,Y)$ with cdf is given by

$F_Z(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & y<0\\
 F_X(x)/2& 0 \leq y < 1\\
F_X(x) & else.
\end{cases}$

Now, what I'm interested in is a pdf of $Z$. Is

$
f_Z(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
0 & y<0\\
f_X(x)/2& 0 \leq y < 1\\
f_X(x) & else.
\end{cases}
$

the pdf of $Z$? More generally, I'm interested in the joint pdf of independent random variables, one of which is continuous and the others (possibly more than one) are discrete. If correct, can the above be applied in this case?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If one of the variables is discrete and the other continuous, they can't have a common density [neither with respect to the Lebesgue-measure, nor the counting measure].

Comment: Ah, ok, I see. Thanks!

Comment: @Dominik Would you care to elaborate a bit? In particular, what is wrong with the expression $f_Z (x,y)$ in the question? I mean, are you saying that we can not make any probabilistic statements about the events of the sort I flip a coin and draw a number from [0,1] - what is the density of observing heads and 0.5?

Comment: The expression is simply wrong. They can't have a joint density, since the set $N = \mathbb{R} \times \{0, 1\}$ is a Lebesgue-Nullset, but $P(Z \in N) = 1$.

Comment: @Dominik Okay. But can we say something about $P(Z \in [0,1/2] \times {0})$? I would say it should be 1/4 no?

Comment: Yes, that's because the random variables $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This implies $P(Z \in [1, 1/2] \times \{0\}) = P(X \in [0, 1/2], Y \in \{0\}) = P(X \in [0, 1/2])P(Y \in \{0\}) = 1/4$.

Comment: @Dominik So the cdf of $Z$ is well-defined but the pdf is not. Is this a general feature when considering the joint distribution of two independent random variables with one discrete and one continuous?

Comment: Yes, this doesn't even have anything to do with the independence. The join distribution of a continuous and a discrete random variable never has a pdf.

Comment: @Dominik And regarding the thing you mentioned in your first answer about the Lebesgue and counting measure. Can I say that the set $N = \mathbb{R}\times \{0,1\}$ has measure zero with respect to the Lebesgue measure but measure infinity with respect to the counting measure? Or, even more generally, that the set $N$ has either measure zero or infinity for any measure and therefore we cannot construct a probability space for $N$?

Comment: No, the set $N$ has measure $1$ with respect to measure that is induced by $Z$. The problem isn't any kind of definition of the distribution of $Z$ [because its distribution is well-defined], you just can't write a density of this distribution with respect to either the Lebesgue- or counting measure. To see that it is true for the counting measure, observe that $P(Z \in \{(a, b)\}) = 0$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: So, I realize that I did not quite understand your reply in the first place. To make sure I understand this time around: we seem to run into this impossibility because we can't write a density of this distribution with respect to either the Lebesgue- or counting measure - why is it crucial that it's either of these two measures? Thanks a lot for your time and help with this, @Dominik!

Comment: It isn't crucial. As I've already stated, everything is well-deefined. But when you talk about a density, it is usually meant with respect to the Lebesgue- or counting measure. In this special case, you simply can't characterize the distribution with such a density.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_probability_distribution#Mixed_case
Wikipedia says there can be a mxied joint density